# Text highlight in image

Tags: window, google-drive, jpeg, png, mjpeg

I have articles of newspaper in png format, want to highlight these images similar to pdf text, is there any possible tool or method to do it? 
I have syncronized this images in my desktop to cloud google drive account, Is there any tool for google drive, it will greatly help for me?
PS: If this question is not relevant to this site can you redirect to apt site.
 [image: Image_Format] 
Expected output is done in pdf format.
[image: Expected_format]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SnagIt (Techsmith) for this. You can open the PNG file with the SnagIt Editor, highlight, add text, encircle text to make it obvious, add arrows and so on. Then re-save. You can easily sync such edited files with Google, One Drive or Dropbox, but the editing is done in your Windows computer

If Windows is up to date, you can also do this with Snip and Sketch (native to Windows) but I prefer SnagIt

Comment: Hello John, it is for 15 days only, right? can't I get a free tool or other tools?

Comment: The SnagIt free trial is 15 days, yes. Snip and Sketch comes with Windows 10 and so is free